# Laravel testing with group prefix

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5.1

I have a group for api:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function () {

    Route::get('abc', function () {
        return 'abc';
    });
  );
```

But, when testing use `$this->call('GET', '/api/abc)` or `$this->call('GET', 'path_to_abc')`, I always get 404 error, although I've printed the url and I can visit that link on browser

Comment: Is any other routes are working in your test case files?

Comment: No, I just wrote 1 basic test

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't configured your `TestCase.php` file, you need to set your app url there as

File: TestCase.php

```
 /**
 * The base URL to use while testing the application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $baseUrl = 'http://YOUR_APP_URL';
```

Comment: Not working. I used absolute path like: http://localhost/.../abc but still get error